# Unable to add two f64 numbers together

Tags: rust, addition

I have two `f64` numbers I wish to add together, however the following code produces an error. How can I go about adding these two floats together?

Code:

```
total_duration = 0.925338 + 0.741495;
```

Error:

```
src/main.rs:56:26: 56:57 error: the trait `core::ops::Add<_>` is not implemented for the type `f64` [E0277]
src/main.rs:56         total_duration = r.elapsed_time + total_duration;
```

Comment: Your code works [in the playpen](http://is.gd/6M9BtE).

Comment: Your error message indicates a completely different line than the one you've indicated is causing the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, there is one line of code, are you OK? It could ONLY be that line.

Comment: @JacobClark it seems there are at least 56 lines of code, and the one in the error message doesn't **at all** look like the one you claim to cause the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If that's your only line, then the rust compiler has a pretty serious bug. You should file a bug report. It should be complaining about expecting an item, since an assignment statement cannot appear outside of a function. The error you should be getting is something like this: `src/main.rs:1:1: 1:15 error: expected item, found 'total_duration'
src/main.rs:1 total_duration = 0.925338 + 0.741495;`

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because you mix `f64` with `f32`.
You may have to specify the type when you do this kind of additions:

```rust
let total_duration = 0.925338f64 + 0.741495f64;
```

You don't have to do this when you add two variables that already are type f64:

```rust
let x: f64 = 0.925338;
let y: f64 = 0.741495;
let total_duration = x + y;
```

I'm not getting an error though when using your code, is your compiler up to date?